# Axios - problems with setting X-CSRF-TOKEN in POST request

Tags: axios, http-headers

To send some data to the url, I first need to the get X-CSRF-TOKEN using the GET request. The GET request passes every time without a problem but I cannot seem to get the POST request to work. I am certain that the token is in `tokenResponse.headers['x-csrf-token']` as I am priting it to the console and I have also tried just copying it to Postman where the request passed without a problem.

Overall Postman doesn't have the same problem as Axios in my app e.g. all requests pass fine.

The error I get (403 CSRF token validation failed) suggests a token mismatch but I am sending the correct data in it. Is there a possiblity that Axios cannot deal with some characters or that I am sending it in a wrong format?

The request and response.request fields in the error both contain the correct header value for the token.

```js
const tokenResponse = await axios.get('https://URL/Request', {
            auth: {
                username: 'user',
                password: 'pass',
            },
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': 'Fetch',
            },
        });
const response = await axios.post(
        'https://URL/Request',
        { Request: [] },
        {
              auth: {
                    username: 'user',
                    password: 'pass',
              },
              headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': tokenResponse.headers['x-csrf-token'],
              },
        }
);
```